# Google Cloud Functions Deployment Error: Missing main.py and GOOGLE_FUNCTION_SOURCE not specified

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, gcloud, google-cloud-scheduler

Im trying to deploy my first GCloud Function within their Webinterface and facing the following Error:
Build failed: missing main.py and GOOGLE_FUNCTION_SOURCE not specified. Either create the function in main.py or specify GOOGLE_FUNCTION_SOURCE to point to the file that contains the function;

We actually have the main.py with our function in it and also the requirements.txt with the extern Python Packages (beautifulsoup4) but we still get this error. The entry point is the default hello_pubsub() function which calls our own function, a little webscraper.

Our folder structure looks like this:

```
folder.zip
    main.py
    requirements.txt
```

Does anyone have an Idea what we´re missing?

At first we missed the requirements.txt, but we still got this error after adding it.